# Space before <?PHP tags causes an error in Slim

Tags: php, slim

I am new to this PHP Micro Framework.

I have been taking a look at it lately before I got stuck with these errors.

[image: Displayed Errors]

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening &lt;?php tag?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\slim3\codecourse\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php:552
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\slim3\codecourse\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(344): Slim\App-&gt;finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\slim3\codecourse\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(298): Slim\App-&gt;process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\slim3\codecourse\public\index.php(17): Slim\App-&gt;run()
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\slim3\codecourse\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php</b> on line <b>552</b><br />
```

I have tried to look for solutions as to what could be the cause for those errors and  I discovered that once there is no space before the `<?php` opening tag those errors are gone, but if you leave space before the `<?php` opening tag those errors appear again.

What could be the cause for that, as far as PHP is concerned?

My Project's folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure1]

Comment: Slim is throwing an exception if there's output before your opening PHP tag, the reason is *probably* because you never want output before your opening PHP tag (.phtml type templates excepted)... it'll screw up any `header()` you attempt to set.

Comment: This is not a bug in Slim. This is a user problem. When spaces occur in files that contain php code, php sends the browsers headers, to which then slim wont because it is no longer in control of any aspect of that flow.

Comment: @CD001@geggleto
My code has no  space before <?php but yet i get errors..
Why is that??

Answer (score 1):

Encoding should be UTF-8 and **NOT** UTF-8 with BOM. Whn using UTF-8 with BOM it add at first byte encoding identification which is in front of `<?php` tag and editors don't show it. That's why it breaks php (pathetic i know :D )

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things to keep in mind:

- PHP is *generally* (there can be exceptions, depending on your setup) output as it is executed. So as soon as there is an `echo` or *anything outside PHP tags*, that is sent directly to the browser.
- Due to the way HTTP works, headers must be sent before content. Once you have sent content, you cannot set any further headers.

The interplay of these two factors means that opening space before your first PHP tag renders a script unable to send any HTTP headers. Apparently Slim is trying to set some headers, but cannot. I must say that the error message it gives you is reasonably informative.

Comment: ,my codes start at line #1 with <?PHP ,meaning there is no blank space before the opening tags of PHP..

The error makes no sense as to my observations

Comment: @AgApeAmAdeuskAmAgenge Unicode BOM, perhaps? Try taking a hexdump.

Comment: This error have NOTHING to do with output. It's runtime error and happens before any output even begins.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that, @Tommix, when your own answer says the same as mine: that it's about text output before the opening PHP tag. (The BOM is text: it's just a character, nothing magic.)

Comment: @TRiG your answer says OUTPUT so this means PHP processed file and gave output. In this case PHP couldn't process PHP file (broke at first byte) so therefore there is no any output involved. NO headers and so on :) But your comment about hex dump was correct, or he just could look at encoding in IDE/editor.